# How to modulate Phrygian to Harmonic Minor?

Tags: theory, modes, modulation

Is there any formulation to switch from Phrygian mode to Harmonic minor in same key. Like from A Phrygian to A Harmonic Minor.

What I thought so far?

A Phrygian Notes:

> A Bb C D E F G A

A Harmonic Minor Notes:

> A B C D E F G# A

Since we got difference on B and G notes I thought going from G# to G but it does not sound well (Obviously) and then tried Bb to B once more they are half-step away and it did not do well netiher.

So my question is how to switch between these two scales smoothly?

Comment: There’s no formulation that I’m aware of but I prefer using common tones in general to link parallel scales or harmonies. Are you composing or improvising?

Comment: I try to improvise and get some Andalusian tones by mixing these two scales/modes (I don't know the correct term)

Comment: The uncommon tones, 2 and 7 are not strong melodic notes in either scale but good passing tones, try exploiting the differences by alternating the same pattern with the two scales, for example C B A B C, C Bb A Bb C or E F G Bb A, E F G# B A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change will probably occur at the end of a phrase at least - not right in the middle! So the new 'key' of Am can be preceded with a run up maybe E F G G♯ to the 'new' root of A.

It's not that much of a change - parallel keys get used an awful lot. And since both are A minor based, it will depend on what harmonies are going on underneath. You seem to be mixing scales and keys, name-wise. They're not synonymous, and there's nothing wrong with mixing and matching all the notes from both. Accidentals are made for doing that.